# NSMutableData replacing bytes

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledata

I'm trying to replace bytes in correct order (server sends them in bad order). And I'm having a hard time getting it done. Maybe someone could help me do this correctly

```
Input:  < F801 0020 > (NSMutableData)
Output: < 2000 01F8 > (NSMutableData)
```

Tried using `replaceBytesInRange:<(NSRange)> withBytes:<(const void *)>`

But I'm having a hard time using this method for this problem. Isn't there a simple method of swapping bytes in objective-c ?

Comment: Is the sequence of swapping fixed like you mention above?

Comment: Well yes, but i have already figure it out. If you have better idea on how to do this please post an answer :)

Comment: Doing it with `replaceBytesInRange` is going to be slow & clumsy.  Would probably be better/simpler/faster to just read one NSMutableData and write another, assuming that the entire NSMutableData object must be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working this way

```
+ (int) dataToIntSwitched:(NSMutableData*) data
{
    int elem = OSReadLittleInt([data bytes], 0);
    return elem;
}
```